# Complicated model item in PyQt

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to use Model-View in PyQt. I have a QStandardItemModel and QListView. I am trying to add a QStandardItem in my model. I only can add text and Icon. But what if I want to add, for example two or three icons. Is it possible to add a layout, and some widgets to my item?

This is my code:

```
class SponsorsHorizontal(QtWidgets.QWidget, Ui_SponsorsHorizontal):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.partners_model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
        self.partners_list_view.setModel(self.partners_model)

        icon = QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap(path_convert('resources/logos/' + object[i]['logo'])))

        item = QtGui.QStandardItem(icon, object[i]["name"] + "     ")
        item.setTextAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        self.partners_model.appendRow(item)
```

I know we can add widget with a layout and random count of items in QListWIdget and QListWidgetItem. Can I do something similar in Model in Qt ?

Comment: If you want to change the way a list item is displayed in a `QListView`, you need to look at delegates (`QStyledItemDelegate`). But I think it's easier to do this with `QListWidget`.

Comment: @tmoreau thanks, I will check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i played with `QStyledItemDelegate` just for fun and to learn, how to place text and other elements  in the items rect by delegate.

You can add a list of icons to the model (UserRole) for each item. Subclass `QStyledItemDelegate` and overwrite `paint()` to paint the icons by delegate like this

[image: several icons in listViewItems]

here a working example setting the icons by random:

```
import sys, random
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets

class ViewDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate.__init__(self) 
        self.padding = 2
        self.AlignmentFlag =  QtCore.Qt.AlignRight

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        x = option.rect.x()
        y = option.rect.y()
        width = option.rect.width()
        height = option.rect.height()
        iconList = index.data(256)                      # get the icons associated with the item
        text = index.data()                             # get the items text

        for a, i in enumerate(iconList):
            m = max([i.width(), i.height()]) 
            f = (height- 2*self.padding)/m                  # scalingfactor
            i = i.scaled(int(i.width()*f),int(i.height()*f))                    # scale all pixmaps to the same size depending on lineheight
            painter.drawPixmap(QtCore.QPoint(x,y+self.padding),i)
            x += height

        painter.drawText(QtCore.QRect(x + self.padding,y + self.padding, width - x - 2*self.padding, height - 2*self.padding),self.AlignmentFlag, text)

class MyWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget): 
    def __init__(self): 
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self) 
        self.setGeometry(200,100,200,220)
        self.icons = []
        for i in ('arrow_double.svg', 'asc.png', 'desc.png', 'checked.png'):
            icon = QtGui.QPixmap(i)
            self.icons.append(icon)

        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListView(self)
        self.delegate = ViewDelegate()
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(20,20,160,180)
        self.listWidget.setItemDelegate(self.delegate)
        self.model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(self.listWidget)

        itemsTexts = ['abcde','fghij','klmno','pqrst','uvwxy','zABCD']

        for r, i in enumerate(itemsTexts):
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(i)              
            self.model.setItem(r,0, item)
            self.model.setData(self.model.index(r,0), self.iconList(), 256) # save the items icons in userRole

        self.listWidget.setModel(self.model)

    def iconList(self):                             # creates a random iconList 
        r = random.randint(1,len(self.icons))                   # Anzahl icons in the list
        iconList = []
        for i in range(0,r):
            n = random.randint(0,len(self.icons)-1)
            icon = self.icons[n]
            iconList.append(icon)
        return iconList

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv) 
widget = MyWidget()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: ohhh, yeah, it is a great solution. It helps! Thank you